# Zsh error on shell start - Library loading issue

Tags: zsh

Getting this error on shell startup via zsh.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh
  Reason: image not found
zsh: trace trap
```

Comment: A more interesting question is, did this use to work, and how did the library then disappear?

Comment: Yes this used to work. I don't know how this library disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying that it cannot find the libpcre file, which is the perl compatible regular expression library.

To fix this make sure pcre is installed and then create a symlink to the appropriate file.

On MAC run

```
brew install pcre

ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.35/lib/libpcre.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
```

Make sure to change the version in the above command to the appropriate version that is installed on your system.

Comment: But how do you run any command when you cannot open the terminal?

Comment: @DoronGold Open a different shell.
In terminal on mac, open settings, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. There's a section called "Shells open with", if you are having troubles with zsh, open bash. It's located at `/bin/bash`